# Read *.au file in python

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to read an audio file of type `.au` in python. I would like to have a vector with the amplitudes of the waveform contained in the audio file much in the same way as I can read `*.wav` files with `scipy`:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
rate,sig=wav.read('filename')
```

There is a built-in module for opening `*.au` files, i.e. `sunau` but I did not manage getting the amplitude vector using it. If I use the function 'sunau.Au_read' I can open a file but I am not able to extract the numbers I want but I can only do something like:

```
In [44]: f=sunau.Au_read('sound.au')
In [45]: f.readframes(10)
Out[45]: '\x0c\x02\x0c\x02,\x02L\x02\x14\x01,\x02,\x02\xec\x01L\x02\x04\x01'
```

I have no idea what to do with that string... In Matlab there is the function 'auread', is there an equivalent in Python?

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: sunau returns binary data encoded as a string.  You should be able convert it to a numpy vector with something like `audio_data = np.fromstring(f.readframes(10), dtype=np.int16)`

Comment: That works, thanks. :) I was just missing the conversion from the string to an np array.

Comment: You need to be careful to make the dtype match the data in the au file.  On my mac, for a "pcm16" au file, I had to use `dtype=np.dtype('>h')` to get the right byte swapping.

Comment: Alright... I think I got it. With `np.fromstring()` I can interpret a sequence of bytes in my memory as a sequence of items of the specified datatype. So I have to know which is the correct datatype as I would end up with a complete nonsense interpretation of my memory otherwise. Thanks for your help!